# Why is there so much spacing between my tableview header and navigation controllers large title

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit, ios15

So there is a lot of space between my TableView section headers and my Navigation Controllers Large title. I'm doing the EXACT thing for the two controllers and still there is a difference.

[image: Screenshot about to much space]
[image: Screenshot about to less space]

Already tried a lot but couldn't find a solution. What I've tried so far is:

- Uncheck - Adjust scroll view insets.
- `tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never`
- Setting the headers is the same with a `switch case`

Comment: Difficult to say without any code. Can you provide it?

Comment: `tableView.sectionHeaderTopPadding = 0.0`

Comment: @B2Fq thanks man! By searching this I've fout that in Storyboard there is attribute with an estimate header height that was on some tableviews 0 fixed and some where automatic.

Answer (score 1):

Found out that there is an attribute in storyboard with Estimated Section Title Height, on some controllers it was 0 and some where Automatic. Setting everything the same solved it!

Theres an option to set it by code: (thanks B2Fq)
`tableView.sectionHeaderTopPadding = 0.0`

Comment: This is how to answer your own question. (i.e. not by editing the question...)

Comment: tableView.sectionHeaderTopPadding = 0.0 can solve the problem. Just for iOS 15.0 and a above. Thanks Kets